# Login Dropbox within Webview2 error message "Your browser appears to be blocking dropboxcaptcha.com, which is required for authentication.."

Tags: authentication, dropbox

I got an issue recently that login Dropbox account within webview2, after type username and passward then hit next, the message will show up on the top said "Your browser appears to be blocking dropboxcaptcha.com, which is required for authentication.". Any help will be appreciated.

WebView Version:
SDK: 1.0.902.49
Runtime: 92.0.902.55
Framework: WPF
OS: Win10

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2):

please check in browser site and pop up options and enable. This worked for me in brave browser.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31347248)